# error uploading file via php

Tags: php

I am using this script to upload files. I am not perfoming any check on filetype since its the first time I am trying. I am using Ubuntu and in php.ini file file upload is set to 'on'. But still I am not able to upload file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
$uploaddir = "/home/harbhag/Desktop/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

}
?>

<html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="send" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the (write) permissions on the `$uploaddir` directory?

Comment: @helle, I have the write permissions on $uploaddir since its my home directory. @alexn, I get "possible file upload attack" which is written in the code. But I dont get any message specifying the possible cause of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `$uploaddire` and `$uploadfile` both variables to make a valid path for file.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$uploadfile)) {
```

And also note the points

1. Destination directory should have write permissions
2. Size of File to be uploaded must meet php's `upload_max_filesize` (default value is 2MB )limit

Comment: It didn't help. Yes upload_max_filesize is already set to 50MB

Comment: Ok, I have solved it. I changed the directory to someother and given it the full write permissions and It worked. I did not need to use $uploaddir

Answer (score 1):

Be extra careful when using `move_uploaded_file`. It will not move files between partitios, and hostng companies may have their upload temp directory elsewhere tha your php files.

It's a safer choice to use:

```
$tempname = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
if (is_uploaded_file($tempname)) {
    copy($tempname, $uploadfile);
}
```